# Azure container often connecting to 23.97.221.176:11041. What is this port for?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-web-app-service

I'm monitoring my App Service Linux containers on Azure. I use netstat to see which outgoing connections are made. I can explain them all except one: 23.97.221.176:11041

Is there someone out there who knows which service uses port 11041?

Answer (score 1):

11041 is not a well known port number. It looks like you're leveraging a custom container. Most Docker images have environment variables that need to be configured. If you are using an existing Docker image built by someone else, the image may use a port other than 80. You tell Azure about the port that your image uses by using the WEBSITES_PORT app setting.

Additionally, only one container can be open for access
Only port 80 and 8080 is accessible (exposed ports)

Here are the rules for determining which container is accessible - in the order of precedence:

Application setting WEBSITES_WEB_CONTAINER_NAME set to the container name

The first container to define port 80 or 8080

If neither of the above is true, the first container defined in the
   file will be accessible (exposed)

If it's a custom container listening to a port other than port 80, you could the app route requests to that port:

There is a automatic port detection. As mentioned above, you can also specify an app setting called WEBSITES_PORT and give it the value of the expected port number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of everything you've written. However, I found out that our app when running on a Windows app service also connects to this specific IP address on this specific port so in hindsight, it has nothing to do with Linux containers. A Microsoft support engineer is currently looking into the issue. 
I also don't understand why you would write something about WEBSITES_PORT as that has more to do with incoming connections than outgoing connections....

Comment: Thanks for the update. Kindly do post back the outcome of the support investigation to benefit the community. Just to highlight the difference of port usage (inbound vs outbound).